# Where are cpp files from libqgis?

Tags: qgis, qt

I am in linux Mint 17.0

I am trying to develop a small application in Qt using libqgis library.

When I create a Class inherit from QgsMapCanvas, I get mistakes related with 'undefined references to...'

I have search the *.cpp files (e.g. qgsmapcanvas.cpp) and I haven't it.

I have installed libqgis-dev. I can found all the *.h files into the packet installed in /usr/include/qgis, but there aren't cpp files, and this is the reason that compilar is claiming.

And this is the question. ¿Where are the cpp files?

Comment: "dev" packages contain developer tools. "src" packages contain sources. This isn't GIS-specific; it's just the way Linux works.

Comment: @Vince could you make this an answer?

Comment: I suspect there's also an error in the OP's code if the dev package isn't enough, but that error and the code that produces it belongs elsewhere in the SE hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but there aren't cpp files, and this is the reason that compilar is claiming.

No.
The reason your compiler (or rather linker) is complaining is that it's missing the symbols of the functions declared in the header files. You do not need the cpp files to develop with the QGIS library.

What you need are

- the header files (for the includes)
- the library files (libqgis_core.so.x.y.z / libqgis_gui.so.x.y.z)

You will need to tell your build system (see e.g. [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664693/makefile-compiling-and-linking) / [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html)) to tell your linker to link your application against the QGIS libraries.

Since your actual question was, where are the cpp files: [you find them here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS)

Comment: Thanks. It's solved my error. I wrote `\LIBS += -L/usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.8.1 /usr/lib/libqgis_gui.so.2.8.1` in pro file. Now it crash, but it is another problem.

Comment: for the includes, should we write every subfolder for the header files? Or is there a recursive include? detailed version of my question is here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431152/qt-pro-file-includepath-issue